# In Julia, how do I display the contents of a macro?

Tags: macros, julia

For example, I want to see what's "inside" of the @time macro.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 7):

While it doesn't show you the macro itself, you can see the results of the macro expansion with [`macroexpand`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=macroexpand#Base.macroexpand).  For example:

```
julia> macroexpand(:(@time rand(10)))
:(begin  # util.jl, line 38:
        local #60#b0 = Base.gc_bytes() # line 39:
        local #61#t0 = Base.time_ns() # line 40:
        local #62#val = rand(10) # line 41:
        local #63#t1 = Base.time_ns() # line 42:
        local #64#b1 = Base.gc_bytes() # line 43:
        Base.println("elapsed time: ",Base./(Base.-(#63#t1,#61#t0),1.0e9)," seconds (",Base.-(#64#b1,#60#b0)," bytes allocated)") # line 44:
        #62#val
    end)
```

In this case, it also shows you where it is defined (util.jl, line 38), but that doesn't always happen.  Since macros aren't first class objects themselves, the utilities such as `which`/`edit`/`less` (or their macro equivalents) don't work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a built in way to do this, but you can search the codebase for ["macro X"](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/search?l=julia&q=macro+time&type=Code).

This sounds like it would be a useful feature, so unless someone corrects me and it already exists, you could always open an issue requesting it.

Answer (score 1):

At least since 0.5, you can `@less` macros too:

```
julia> @less @time x
```

will open up an editor, which shows the code

```
macro time(ex)
    quote
        local stats = gc_num()
        local elapsedtime = time_ns()
        local val = $(esc(ex))
        elapsedtime = time_ns() - elapsedtime
        local diff = GC_Diff(gc_num(), stats)
        time_print(elapsedtime, diff.allocd, diff.total_time,
                   gc_alloc_count(diff))
        val
    end
end
```